# Oracle does not catch ora-4036 pga limit exceeds exception

Tags: oracle, error-handling, oracle19c

I can not catch this error 4036 in neverending cycle populating collection with random string, why?

In package err:

```
 pga_limit EXCEPTION;
 PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (pga_limit, -4036);
```

Then in cycle:

```
LOOP
    
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('Cycle tick: '||to_char(i,'99,999,999'));
    /* Put cycle logic here, call some unit... */ 
    BEGIN
    newlist(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('a',128);  
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN  err.pga_limit
     THEN dbms_output.put_line('Reached PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT on tick: '||i);
          DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('Cycle reached PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT on tick '||i);
          DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('Cycle END by limit PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT');
         
    END;
    /* If flag false then maximum speed without sleep */ 
    i := i + 1;
    IF nvl(flag,TRUE) THEN DBMS_LOCK.sleep(nvl(tick,1));
    ELSE NULL;
    END IF;
    /* Check for message */
    IF DBMS_PIPE.receive_message(pipename, 0) = 0 THEN
      /* Detect message and exit if it is STOP message*/
      DBMS_PIPE.unpack_message(pipebuf);
      EXIT WHEN pipebuf = 'stop';
    END IF;
    
  END LOOP;
```

I got exception when memory lack occured but in SQLPlus without my handling:

```
SQL> exec ne_cycle(false);
BEGIN ne_cycle(false); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04036: PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT
```

Wrote exception handler but it does not work

Comment: If you've used all the PGA memory allowed by the instance, what makes you think that by catching the exception you will magically have more memory available so that you can continue processing?

Comment: Are you reading thought or something? Im just trying to test some situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few errors like this one cannot be caught by an exception handler. Two other errors that cannot be handled are ORA-01013 and ORA-03113, see https://orasql.org/2021/08/12/ora-exceptions-that-cant-be-caught-by-exception-handler/ for more details.

It makes sense since your session gets disconnected after this error.

Comment: Of course killed session can not handle but when oracle exceed his own 
 controlled limit why dont handle this? Ok , thanx for feedback.